# Asp.net Virtual User Profile Data Lost On Redirect

Tags: asp.net, session, sitecore, asp.net-membership, sitecore7

I'm trying to set some profile data for virtual users based on server variables being set by a third party. After doing this, I will redirect the user to a t&c page if they have not agreed to the most recent version. I'm currently doing this redirect on page load. For some reason, when this redirect happens a user's profile data is lost. Based on fiddler, the asp session cookie is not being set. I'm not sure if there's a different place I need to do this redirect so that that cookie is set (I believe it is used to persist some user data).

Edit: It seems that profile data is lost between my Sitecore pipeline event that creates the virtual user with the server variables from the third party sometime before page load.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving this logic to `Application_PostAcquireRequestState` but I'm still not sure why this was happening.